# Init an attribute using a spring bean dependency

Tags: wicket

I have a non spring bean class that looks like this:

```
public class ReportFilterManager implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@SpringBean
private IControllersConfigService controllersConfigService;

private List<String> fromGroupOfControllers = controllersConfigService.getAllGroupOfControllersNames();
```

I want to init the fromGroupOfControllers field using a method of the spring bean controllersConfigService. What's the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best way is to pass `controllersConfigService` as a method or a constructor parameter.

The class where you instantiate `ReportFilterManager` should find its way to get `controllersConfigService` somehow.